# Transfer output file of T-SQL statement in SSIS package to another server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an existing SSIS package on my  DB server and I have another server which is the application server which uses this DB server for its operation. This SSIS package, is being used by a job running on the DB server. I would like to add an additional step. That step is just a basic select count(*) query to get count from one table. I implemented that on my test server and gave the output path in the advanced tab as well. And i got the output in a simple text file. 
My question now is, How do i send this output file to my application server instead? Because the output path of a T-SQL server seems to only take local drives. I tried giving the path of my application server(which was being used by the SSIS package already) but the output doesn't come on the text file even 'though it says the job executed successfully. I don't see the necessity to create another SSIS package for just getting a simple count info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UNC path to your application server file system.

Comment: I did. the format looks smthng like this:\\pvuktstgfdb**\Count.txt
I've given this in the output of Transact SQL-file.

Comment: never mind. There was problem with the case. Thanks anyways. :)